# Best way to prevent the system message to be shown with the cookie consent module

Tags: jquery, expressionengine

I have the cookie consent module installed. When users click the allow or disallow link, the will see the ugly standard system message. Is there an easy way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) possibly?

Comment: yeah, could be an option.  even have an unused license lying around. However, maybe a jquery solution would be prettier. 
and another thing that just came to mind: once a user has decided against cookies, how do you remember that choice?

Comment: Ironically, I don't think there is a way you can remember their choice unless you use cookies. Or possibly if they were logged in members you could store some info in their profile.